# What does Ctrl + Alt + F11 do?

Tags: gui

I need help so I can get back to GUI: I just pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> but it took me to a black screen!

What do I do?

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 or  Ctrl+Alt+F2.

Comment: In addition to @karel's answer, you can press and hold the left alt button and press the right arrow button over and over again until you're back to your desktop.